# How to insert a text file into a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c#

I know that a loop is involved in order to insert each word to the BST, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You created an insert function in you binary search tree ... use it.

```
class Program
    {
        static BSTree<string> myTree = new BSTree<string>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            readFile("textfile.txt");
            string buffer = "";
            myTree.InOrder(ref buffer);
            Console.WriteLine(buffer);
        }

        static void readFile(string filename)
        {
            const int MAX_FILE_LINES = 50000;
            string[] AllLines = new string[MAX_FILE_LINES];

            //reads from bin/DEBUG subdirectory of project directory
            AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);


            foreach (string line in AllLines)
            {
                //split words using space , . ?
                string[] words = line.Split(' ', ',', '.', '?', ';', ':', '!');
                foreach (string word in words)
                {
                    if (word != "")
                        myTree.InsertItem(word.ToLower());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

On another note, I will mention your InOrder function will return a string that starts with ',' character. Not sure if this was intended. Also, for various reasons, you may want to use a StringBuilder instead of manupulating a string.

Comment: You defined myTree within the scope of the Main(string[]) method. To be able to use it within the context of your Program class, you need to define it as a static class variable.